# Make an object rotates by an arbitrary angle and rotates toward a target in Unity

Tags: unity, quaternion

I have an object facing up in Unity. I need it to move from point A to point B, without prior knowledge of where A and B are. So when I place it at point A, I need to rotate it toward point B. I used this:

```
this.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(A.position, B.position);
```

However, before doing the movement, I also need to rotate the object by 90° around the X axis. I used this:

```
this.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

These two functions worked, but separately. When I try to use these two functions together, the last function called overrides the other.

Comment: you need to look into Coroutines so you start the second rotation after the first has finished.

Comment: I'm... pretty sure this is not a good solution. I need to create a quaternion from two quaternions, not use the two rotations one after another.

Comment: Thats not what you imply in your question. By saying "Make an object rotates by an arbitrary angle THEN rotates toward a target". I'm thinking you need to chain together two or more separate rotations.

Comment: Ok, I edited the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should about do it I think. You can use the * operator to multiply quaternions together :

```
  float rotationAngle = 90 ;
        Quaternion qA = Quaternion.FromToRotation(A.position, B.position);
        Quaternion qB = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationAngle, Vector3.right);
        Quaternion qC = qA * qB;
        transform.rotation = qC;
```